# How do I run a standalone Next.js build from a vscode dev container?

Tags: next.js, containers, port

I have a Windows machine with vscode and Docker Desktop. On this machine I am developing a Next app in a Dev Container, and have created a standalone Next build with `pnpm build`.

I then copy the [necessary files](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/output#automatically-copying-traced-files) into the standalone folder:

- `apps/myApp/.next/static`    --> `apps/myApp/.next/standalone/apps/myApp/.next/static`
- `apps/myApp/public`              --> `apps/myApp/.next/standalone/apps/myApp/public`
- `apps/myApp/.env.local`       --> `apps/myApp/.next/standalone/apps/myApp/env.local`

Finally, I run `node apps/myApp/server.js`, which starts the node server on *172.17.0.2:3000* inside the container.

I can now run `curl 172.17.0.2:3000` from the *standalone* folder, and see the right response.

**Question**

If I try to access the server from my browser on my dev machine (the windows machine, i.e. the host), the request just times out without a reply. How do I get access from my host browser?

**Note**

Also, hopping out of the Dev Container and into WSL, and running the server from there, will allow me to access the server from the host browser via `localhost:3000`